# How to resolve this bad_alloc problem?

Tags: c++, poco, bad-alloc

I'm developing an application that needs to interact over FTP. For this communication I am currently using C++, Visual Studio and Poco on Windows.

The following line results in a bad_alloc exception...

```
ftp = new FTPClientSession("127.0.0.1", 21);
```

So I went down and tried initializing a StreamSocket first, also fails...

```
StreamSocket ss = new SocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 21);
```

When going even further down, and it seems the bad_alloc is coming from:

```
IPAddress * ip = new IPAddress("127.0.0.1");
```

That constructor contains: (I see in the debugger that _pImpl isn't initialised)

```
IPAddress::IPAddress(const std::string& addr)
{
_pImpl = IPv4AddressImpl::parse(addr);

if (!_pImpl) throw InvalidAddressException(addr);
}
```

IPv4AddressImpl::parse contains:

```
static IPv4AddressImpl* parse(const std::string& addr)
{
if (addr.empty()) return 0;     
#if defined(_WIN32) 
    struct in_addr ia;
    ia.s_addr = inet_addr(addr.c_str());
    if (ia.s_addr == INADDR_NONE && addr != "255.255.255.255")
        return 0;
    else
        return new IPv4AddressImpl(&ia);
#else
#if __GNUC__ < 3
    struct in_addr ia;
    ia.s_addr = inet_addr(addr.c_str());
    if (ia.s_addr == INADDR_NONE && addr != "255.255.255.255")
        return 0;
    else
        return new IPv4AddressImpl(&ia);
#else
    struct in_addr ia;
    if (inet_aton(addr.c_str(), &ia))
        return new IPv4AddressImpl(&ia);
    else
        return 0;
#endif
#endif
}
```

The following code with inet_addr from Winsock2.h (ws2_32.lib) results in "SOMETHING ELSE".

```
unsigned long ulAddr = INADDR_NONE;
ulAddr = inet_addr("91.183.48.210");
if (ulAddr == INADDR_NONE)
    msg("NONE");
else
    msg("SOMETHING ELSE");
```

I don't see what is going wrong here... Is there a way to debug this further or does someone know what goes wrong?

Comment: When you say "_pimpl is not initialised" do you mean it is assigned the value zero in the IPAddress constructor?

Comment: ip = 0xcccccc { _pImpl = ??? }
CXX0076: Error:

Comment: It's unable to evaluate the expression of _pImpl, thus probably not initialised.

Comment: If that's the value of ip, then it's not the case that _pImpl is uninitialized. The problem is that ip itself is uninitialized. You're looking at the garbage value that ip began life with. If you're still in the constructor, then the "new" expression hasn't finished running yet, and so the assignment to ip hasn't happened. Don't say "ip" when you really want "this."

Comment: Hehe, indeed... Details mather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no rocket scientist but it looks like you'll have to step into `IPv4AddressImpl()` with `ia.s_addr` populated with a pointer to the string `"127.0.0.1"`.

Just out of interest, do you get the error when you use your real IP address instead of the loopback.

And, do you have an FTP server running on that machine?

And, are you *absolutely* certain the string is `"127.0.0.1"`?

**Update:**

There's only really three things that can cause the exception.

- `addr.empty()` is true, unlikely if addr is `"127.0.0.1"`.
- `is.s_addr` is `INADDR_NONE`, again unlikely since `inet_addr()` should have no trouble with 127.0.0.1 (as you've tested).
- the constructor for `IPv4AddressImpl()` returns NULL (or throws the `bad_alloc` exception itself).

That last one seems the most likely, what happens when you write your own code to do it?

```
struct in_addr ia;
ia.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
IPv4Address *x = new IPv4AddressImpl(&ia);
```

In addition, if you breakpoint on the `"if (!_pImpl) throw..."` line and examine `_pImpl`:

- zero means the ::parse returned NULL and it's the `IPAddress()` constructor throwing `bad_alloc`.
- non-zero means ::parse itself threw an exception which could only be from the `IPv4AddressImpl()` constructor.

You may *have* to step into that to debug further.

Comment: Because these are compiled libraries I can't step into the code. Whatever IP I try (over the internet, a domain name or local), they all result in the same. And yes, there is a FTP server running on both my PC and the server over the internet. This actually doesnt' mather for IPAddress.

Comment: No, the FTP server was a long shot. But  if you can view the source, why can you not recompile in debug mode to step into it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only possible cause is the call to

```
inet_addr
```

on the line

```
ia.s_addr = inet_addr(addr.c_str());
```

returns INADDR_NONE which causes 0/NULL to be returned, causing the exception to be thrown.

Can you call inet_addr("127.0.0.1") and see what the results are? If the results are INADDR_NONE, then you'll need to find a good address to inet_addr that makes your system happy.

Here is a link to [inet_addr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738563(VS.85).aspx) in the MSDN documentation.

**Observation**
You are calling the constructor

```
 IPAddress("127.0.0.1");
```

with a const char*, but the constructor takes a const references

```
 IPAddress::IPAddress(const std::string& str);
```

is the compiler smart enough to create that temporary? I tried it out with VS 2003, and it seems to be ok. I suspect that the language should be smart enough to handle this, but I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: That was my first thought but inet_addr is a very simple function and should have no trouble with "127.0.0.1".

Comment: WinSock2.h, ws2_32.lib, inet_addr indeed results in a good address.

Comment: Regarding the conversion to a reference, yes the compiler is smart enough - this is a very common idiom in C++.